# Hacer que Java imprima un programa con constructor

Tags: java, bucle-for, constructor

soy nuevo en la programación con constructores (recién lo estoy aprendiendo), estaba intentando hacer un programa donde se impriman 5 veces valores aleatorios (con rangos establecidos) con un for y con un switch, y por alguna extraña razón que no encuentro no arroja nada. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo corregir esto?
Este es el código:

```
    package Reto;

import java.util.Random;

public class Reto {
public Reto(){
Random rand=new Random();
   int ojos=rand.nextInt(3)+1;
  int  piel=rand.nextInt(5)+1;
  int  altura=rand.nextInt(4)+1;
  int  objetos=rand.nextInt(5)+1;
  int  arreglar=rand.nextInt(5)+1;
  int  destructivo=rand.nextInt(5)+1;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        switch(i){
        case 1:
        {
        System.out.println("El auxiliar 1 tiene "+ojos+" ojos, su color de piel es "+piel+", su altura es "+altura+", su nivel para crear objetos es de "+objetos+", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de "+arreglar+", y su nivel destructivo es de "+destructivo);
        }
        case 2:
        {
        System.out.println("El auxiliar 2 tiene "+ojos+" ojos, su color de piel es "+piel+", su altura es "+altura+", su nivel para crear objetos es de "+objetos+", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de "+arreglar+", y su nivel destructivo es de "+destructivo);
        }
        case 3:
        {
        System.out.println("El auxiliar 3 tiene "+ojos+" ojos, su color de piel es "+piel+", su altura es "+altura+", su nivel para crear objetos es de "+objetos+", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de "+arreglar+", y su nivel destructivo es de "+destructivo);
        }
        case 4:
        {
        System.out.println("El auxiliar 4 tiene "+ojos+" ojos, su color de piel es "+piel+", su altura es "+altura+", su nivel para crear objetos es de "+objetos+", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de "+arreglar+", y su nivel destructivo es de "+destructivo);
        }
        case 5:
        {
        System.out.println("El auxiliar tiene "+ojos+" ojos, su color de piel es "+piel+", su altura es "+altura+", su nivel para crear objetos es de "+objetos+", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de "+arreglar+", y su nivel destructivo es de "+destructivo);
        {
        break;
        }
}
}
}
```

De antemano, gracias!

Comment: Por curiosidad en donde o como tienes declaro tú metodo **`Main`**

Comment: No añadí el método Main, ya que no encontré la manera de meter el código dentro de este teniendo un nombre de clase distinto (Reto), como dije, soy algo nuevo en los constructores y eso me genera complicaciones :(

Comment: Dentro del Main solo llamas al constructor de la clase asi: `new Reto();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.
Crea una clase llamada Reto con el código siguiente:

```
public class Reto 
{
    private int ojos;
    private int piel;
    private int altura;
    private int objetos;
    private int arreglar;
    private int destructivo;
    private Random rand;

    //Constructor de la clase
    Reto()
    {
        this.rand=new Random();
        this.ojos=rand.nextInt(3)+1;
        this.piel=rand.nextInt(5)+1;
        this.altura=rand.nextInt(4)+1;
        this.objetos=rand.nextInt(5)+1;
        this.arreglar=rand.nextInt(5)+1;
        this.destructivo=rand.nextInt(5)+1;

        //Ya no hace falta el switch porque puedes usar la variable i para cambiar el auxiliar
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("El auxiliar "+i+" tiene "+this.ojos+" ojos, su color de piel es "+this.piel+", su altura es "+this.altura+", su nivel para crear objetos es de "+this.objetos+", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de "+this.arreglar+", y su nivel destructivo es de "+this.destructivo);
        }
    }
}
```

Tambien puedes omitir el switch simplemente imprimiendo el contador, para que el código se vea mas limpio.

Y ya simplemente para llamar una instancia de esa clase crea una clase mas (con el nombre que quieras) con el método main con el siguiente código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Reto reto=new Reto();
    }
```

Al instanciar el objeto automáticamente se ejecutara el código del constructor de la clase. 
Otra cosa, con ese código que manejas los numero aleatorios serán los mismos para todos los auxiliares, si quieres que cambien para cada auxiliar las variables que están en el contructor antes del for debes ponerlas dentro del for (excepto el random).

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo

Comment: A la hora de llamar a Reto, también puedes escribir directamente new Reto() y te ejecuta el código sin tener que crear una instancia.

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta un método main para que se pueda correr. Una propuesta es renombrar tú constructor como si fuera el método main:

```
package Reto;
import java.util.Random;
public class Reto {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int ojos = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        int piel = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        int altura = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        int objetos = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        int arreglar = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        int destructivo = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            switch (i) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("El auxiliar 1 tiene " + ojos + " ojos, su color de piel es " + piel + ", su altura es " + altura + ", su nivel para crear objetos es de " + objetos + ", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de " + arreglar + ", y su nivel destructivo es de " + destructivo);
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("El auxiliar 2 tiene " + ojos + " ojos, su color de piel es " + piel + ", su altura es " + altura + ", su nivel para crear objetos es de " + objetos + ", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de " + arreglar + ", y su nivel destructivo es de " + destructivo);
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("El auxiliar 3 tiene " + ojos + " ojos, su color de piel es " + piel + ", su altura es " + altura + ", su nivel para crear objetos es de " + objetos + ", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de " + arreglar + ", y su nivel destructivo es de " + destructivo);
                }
                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("El auxiliar 4 tiene " + ojos + " ojos, su color de piel es " + piel + ", su altura es " + altura + ", su nivel para crear objetos es de " + objetos + ", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de " + arreglar + ", y su nivel destructivo es de " + destructivo);
                }
                case 5: {
                    System.out.println("El auxiliar tiene " + ojos + " ojos, su color de piel es " + piel + ", su altura es " + altura + ", su nivel para crear objetos es de " + objetos + ", su nivel para arreglar cosas es de " + arreglar + ", y su nivel destructivo es de " + destructivo);
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Y donde dejas el constructor de la clase?

Comment: Por defecto la clase tiene un constructor, aun así lo puedes agregar antes del método máin: public Reto(){
        
    }

Comment: Entonces de que vale aprender a utilizar los contructores (Que es lo que pregunta el OP) si a la final no se implementan de forma explicita.

Comment: excelente pregunta, tienes razón

Comment: Creo que la obtención de aleatorios debe estar dentro del ciclo; sino no van a servir. Y el ciclo debiera ser del 0 al 5, y el case iniciar con 0.

Comment: @AlbertoLopez tienes razon, en cuanto a iniciar desde cero mmm, no se si el `+1` despues del `nextInt` arroje algun cero para compara en el case.